# Using Strings as KEY of map in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hashmap

Im using this 'map' on js:

```
   var myMap = new Object();
   myMap[key1]=value1; //like this n times...
```

but i want to use the key as some combination of two strings meaning:

```
  function getMapValue(str1,str2){...}
```

i dont mind joining the two strings into one long string and use the function with the long string

any ideas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what it is you're asking here. Could you try clarifying your question, or providing a more complete example?

Comment: i just want to use this self generated map. and i want the key to be a string, or maybe transform the string into integer... just looking for an idea of how could it e done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a map of maps (just be sure to check that the intermediate map exists when accessing it)

```
var myMap = {}; //dont use "new Object()". It is evil.

function insert(k1, k2, v){
   if(!(k1 in myMap)){ myMap[k1] = {}; }
   myMap[k1][k2] = v;
}

function get(k1, k2){
   return myMap[k1] && myMap[k1][k2];
}
```

And if you want to join two substrings into a single one you can use the plus operator to concatenate things.

```
var customKey = k1 + '|' + k2;
```

Just be sure your separator can't be used in a normal key to avoid conflicts.

Comment: `myMap[k1] && myMap[k1][k2]` would return true or false, not the value of [k1][k2]

Comment: @jontro:In Javascript `&&` returns the left operand if it is falsy and the right operand otherwise. This kind of use of `&&` and `||` is a normal JS pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, the following should help:

```
var myMap = {"key1" : "something1", "key2" : "something2"};
```

to get value for a key, you you use, either: `return myMap.key1;`

Or: `return myMap.["key1"];`

If you had/did: `myMap["key1key2"] = "MagicHappens!";`

you could use `myMap.key1key2` to get the value or `myMap["key1key2"]`, or even: `return myMap["key1"+"key2"];`

Or:

```
var x = "key1";
var y = "key2";
return myMap[x+y];
```

in your getter function, you get the two variables for the keys which you can then directly use.